# Django delete function overrides pgtrigger

Tags: python, django, postgresql, triggers, crud

I have created several models using Django, for one of the models I would like to have a trigger that does not allow deletes. See the model code below.

```
@pgtrigger.register(
    pgtrigger.Protect(name='protect_deletes',operation=pgtrigger.Delete)
)
class NoDelete(models.Model):
    salary = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The application also has an website that allows you to interact with the database, when deleting a model of this type a function in views.py is called.

```
def delete(request, id):
    temp = NoDelete.objects.get(pk=id)
    temp.delete()
```

So it seems like the trigger does not function as I want it to since this delete removes the row from the database. When trying to delete the tuple directly from the database however the trigger is fired. Any ideas on how to get around this issue? I have to use a trigger in this assignment.

Comment: I would recommend not using database triggers at all.
Instead use querysets and override their delete method in order to exclude those you don't want to delete. Same deal with overriding the model delete method.

Comment: Could you just remove the DELETE permission for that table from the postgres user that Django uses?